# git - Move existing branch to new child branch

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following situation:

```
                  F---G---H BranchB
                 /
A---B---C---D---E---I---J BranchA
```

and I want that BranchA point to BranchB (commit H) and discard commits I and J, removing then BranchB:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H BranchA
```

Any idea about how to achieve that?

Comment: (BACKUP FIRST!) `git checkout BranchA` → `git reset BranchB` (optionally followed by `git branch -d BranchB`). Also note that if you have pushed BranchA already you need to force-push, make sure you don't lose commits in the remote this way.

Comment: @Lasse Please post a response.

Comment: Backup by creating a temporary branch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To move a branch to a different commit you can use the `git reset` command.

Thus, the steps to make `BranchA` refer to the same commit as `BranchB` does you can use this sequence of git commands:

```
git checkout BranchA
git reset --hard BranchB
```

This will both move the branch pointer as well as clean up your working folder with the files from `BranchB` (which is now also the files of `BranchA`).

Note that if you have already pushed `BranchA` to a remote, you might be denied pushing the updated branch unless you use "force-push".

**When using force push, ensure you do not lose commits in the remote**, but here's how to force-push your updated BranchA branch:

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of terminology:  You may notice I've submitted an edit to your title, because to git the word HEAD (in all caps) means "what's checked out at the moment".  It is true that head can also mean a branch tip, but even then it's not the most straightforward way to ask your question - which may be why you couldn't find an answer.

Because once you know that what you're asking to do is simply *move a branch* to point to the same commit as another branch, the git docs should point you in the right direction.

You can use `git reset`

```
git checkout branchA
git reset --hard branchB
```

Or you can use `branch` with the "force" option

```
git checkout branchB
git branch -f branchA
```

The commits that become "unreachable" - `I` and `J` - still exist (for now).  You can reach them using the reflog, or their commit ID's.  If you think there's a chance you'll want them down the road, you might put a tag on them.  If you don't, eventually the reflog entries for them will expire, and after that they will be discarded by `gc`.

If you move a branch in this way after having pushed it, you will have to use the "force" option to get the remote to accept the update.  This will in turn mean that any other user of that repo has to take recovery steps.  This is equivalent to the "upstream rebase" described in the `git rebase` documentation, so if your repo has other users you should review that information and determine if it's still worth doing.  (Generally it's a best practice to require agreement among affected users to do anything that requires a forced push.)